# Redirected view not rendered from controller Laravel 8, except on the root route

Tags: php, routes, laravel-8

In file Controllers/Auth/Authentication.php :

```
class Authentication extends Controller {
...
public static function signOut(Request $request) {
        Auth::logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        return redirect()->route('guest');
    }
}
```

I see the view in the response, but it never rendered.

In routes/web.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('guest');
    }
});
```

The redirection work here. But if i'm trying somewhere else than the route '/', it not working.
Big question now, Why it work only with the '/' route?

Comment: Please edit your question and try to clarify the problem, it is hard to understand at the moment.  Eg "*I see the view in the response, but it never rendered*" - what does this mean, exactly?  You are seeing raw PHP?  "*it not working*" - OK, what happens? Some errors?

Comment: Redirection work only from root '/'. If i do a redirection from '/something', i see the view in my response but it not displayed on screen. I think my problem come from an nginx setting.